# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.SemaphoreFullException' occurred in System.dll

Tags: c#, multithreading

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.SemaphoreFullException' occurred in System.dll 
Additional information: Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count.

On Button click

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(MAX_THREADS, MAX_THREADS);
semaphore = new System.Threading.Semaphore(MAX_THREADS, MAX_THREADS);

mainDownloadThread =  new Thread(() => startDownload(list));
mainDownloadThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
mainDownloadThread.Start();
```

Main thread goes here

```
void startDownload(List<string> list)
{

    manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    foreach (string link in list)
    {

        ThreadInfo threadInfo = new ThreadInfo();
        threadInfo.Index = threadIndex++;
        threadInfo.link = link;
        threadInfo.ManualResetEvent = manualResetEvent;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProcessRequest), threadInfo);
        totalItems++;
    }
    manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
    base.BeginInvoke(new frmMain.EnableExportDelegate(this.enableInterface), null);

}
```

And processRequest

```
void processRequest(object obj)
{
    try
    {

        ThreadInfo threadInfo = obj as ThreadInfo;
        semaphore.WaitOne();
        manualResetEvent = threadInfo.ManualResetEvent;
        string link = threadInfo.link;

        if (isCancelled == true) return;
        if (manualResetEvent.WaitOne(0, false)) return;

        //stuff
        .
        .
        .
        .
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref this.totalItems) == 0 || isCancelled == true)
        {
            manualResetEvent.Set();
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
        //////Exception thrown on above line//////
    }
}
```

Not sure i'm doing it right or wrong, but after 1 2 clicks on above button, it throws the exception.

Comment: Can you specify what UI are you using like WPF etc.? Also it may be worth checking if you can use Tasks instead of Thread + ManualResetEvent.

Comment: I'm using Winforms

Comment: Semaphore is in general used to block the thread at first and then release them. If you start the semaphore as new Semaphore(1,1) it is already open, I would say you should start as new Semaphore(0,1) and then call the Release(1) from main thread to allow one download thread to proceed.

Comment: And unless you really need some fine grained control over synchronization of the download processes, use the old background worker: https://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Comment: Are you certain that nothing else calls `Release` on that semaphore?

Comment: Yup it's the only call.

Comment: Can you move the semaphore.WaitOne(); outside the try/catch/finally block in processRequest and check it out?

Comment: My suggestion would be to put some code in the `catch` block, and put a breakpoint there. I suspect an exception is being thrown before the `WaitOne` is executed, so you end up with an extra call to `Release`. How that's possible given your code, I don't know. But it's the only possibility I see that could explain the symptoms you report.